# Is it possible to create newsletter editions via API?

Tags: linkedin-api

is there a way to create LinkedIn newsletter editions via API?

I looked through the API docs but couldn't find anything. At the same time this seems such an obvious use-case I thought there must be an endpoint for this.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently it's not possible to create a `LinkedIn Newsletter` using an API. However, what you could do instead is to create an `Article` about a specific topic using the existing [Posts Article API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-04&tabs=http#article-post-creation-sample-request).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, got. But what I could do is create an article, set it to draft, and then manually add it to my newsletter. Which is good enough for me at the moment.